# How do I sort songs in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod-classic

So I have searched and found some suggestions on this but nothing works.

EDIT: I tagged as iPod Classic because that is what is plugged into my Windows PC as I'm trying to sort this songs are in a playlist on the iPod. So I'm trying to sort within the device itself as it's plugged in to iTunes.

I'm in iTunes and I have the songs listed, I imported them to iTunes from a CD I own.  For simplicity it's like this:

```
A Song   (in Song Info it is Track 1 of 3)
Middle Song (in Song Info it is Track 2 of 3)
Ze Last Song (in Song Info it is Track 3 of 3)
```

They appeared in iTunes out-of-order.  Sorting on the "Name" column sorted them in a completely random way.

So I prefixed them as such, figuring Arabic numerals are a little more universally accepted:

```
001-A Song   (in Song Info it is Track 1 of 3)
002-Middle Song (in Song Info it is Track 2 of 3)
003-Ze Last Song (in Song Info it is Track 3 of 3)
```

And--(and I'm not kidding here)--when I sort by clicking the Sort arrow on the "Name" column--it sorts 002, 001,003.  Reverse the sort and--yes, still not kidding, it's  001, 003, 002.

This is actually not just 3 songs, it's all 46 from Hamilton, and I've painstakingly dragged them to the right order looking at the CD and iTunes *STILL* won't sort them properly--the Track#'s are correct and I named them with number-prefixes (no leading spaces or typos) and...
... iTunes is just insane.

I give up Apple.  Can I just play my music in the order it was meant to play?  How can I do this please?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a valuable resource. In terms of your question, could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341694/edit) it to provide some additional details. For example, is this problem only happening with the Hamilton album, or is it something you're experiencing with other albums you import music from? Also, it's not clear why you added the iPod Classic tag to your question, so either we're missing something or you've added that by mistake. Finally, which version of iTunes are you using?

Comment: maybe your songs are tied to the album and will only sort in the order they are on the album. if I open iTunes I have about 600 songs that will sort alphabetically by just clicking on the name. What is difference in my songs and your songs?

Comment: You say import from cd implying iTunes on a mac or Windows but you tag as iPod which does not have iTunes.  Could you please clarify.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  So to clarify--I'm trying to sort the playlist as it sits on the iPod (selecting the playlist under the Device node in iTunes). In the View menu, I've chose View as Songs.  The same craziness occurs sorting that Name column on that playlist as it sits in iTunes (not under the Device node, but under the "Music Playlists" node).   I have Sync off, btw.   But what I finally did was sort by the "ID" column furthest to left, and that seemed to do the trick.  But still--if I click on the Name header one would expect, after years of UX, that it would sort on that column.